# How can i make my svg code polygon shape responsive in all screen

Tags: html, css, responsive

**This is what i am doing right now. i want that svg code to make it responsive.  **

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>          
<html>
<body>
    <svg height="500" width="500">
        <polygon points="126 119,109 132,96 146,87 157,78 171,71 189,66 213,68 239,73 259,84 279,96 287,110 298,127 308,142 316,156 326,169 333,178 339,191 348,203 355,218 361,230 363,242 363,262 361,274 357,291 351,309 343,322 335,342 319,357 306,367 296,377 284,385 268,388 261,392 245,393 236,396 218,394 201,389 185,384 174,381 169,374 155,363 142,356 135,344 125,326 113,314 106,292 97,276 93,249 89,225 88,204 90,187 93,157 103,145 109,136 114" style="fill:red;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1">
         </polygon>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remember to upvote a response that you consider as helpfull thanks ;)

Comment: 18Aug23: 575 views; 1 up-vote?  Come on, guys - participate.  That's how the Stack Overflow resource and community thrive!  :D  <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the `viewbox` attribute that it use like that `viewbox="min-x, min-y, width, height"`. Secondly, I recommand you to wrap your svg in a container like this :

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <polygon points="126 119,109 132,96 146,87 157,78 171,71 189,66 213,68 239,73 259,84 279,96 287,110 298,127 308,142 316,156 326,169 333,178 339,191 348,203 355,218 361,230 363,242 363,262 361,274 357,291 351,309 343,322 335,342 319,357 306,367 296,377 284,385 268,388 261,392 245,393 236,396 218,394 201,389 185,384 174,381 169,374 155,363 142,356 135,344 125,326 113,314 106,292 97,276 93,249 89,225 88,204 90,187 93,157 103,145 109,136 114" style="fill:red;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1">
    </polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and then use css rules to the container to manage svg's size :

```css
.svg-container { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[Link to JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/769o4mfy/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `width` and `height` attributes with `viewBox`, which makes it a lot easier to control.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <polygon points="126 119,109 132,96 146,87 157,78 171,71 189,66 213,68 239,73 259,84 279,96 287,110 298,127 308,142 316,156 326,169 333,178 339,191 348,203 355,218 361,230 363,242 363,262 361,274 357,291 351,309 343,322 335,342 319,357 306,367 296,377 284,385 268,388 261,392 245,393 236,396 218,394 201,389 185,384 174,381 169,374 155,363 142,356 135,344 125,326 113,314 106,292 97,276 93,249 89,225 88,204 90,187 93,157 103,145 109,136 114" style="fill:red;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1">
    </polygon>
</svg>
```

This will make your SVG responsive, but you might want to control the maximum size.

```css
svg {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

This is a simplified way of making it responsive. There are a whole lot of things to concider, and a lot of articles like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) that explains it.